# Utility to cache Google Maps

Tags: go

I wrote a little wrapper for Google Static Maps API so that I do not pull down from Google Maps if I have already retrieved the address. The below code works, but I wrote it in a quick fashion - not really paying attention to the best practices of golang.

Several questions I have about this code:
 - How can I improve the `v := url.Values{}` section?
 - Is there a better method to the `for i := 0; i < 30; i++` loop?

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/hex"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"
)

var apiKey = os.Getenv("API_KEY")

// loadMap generates a new map or returns a cached one
func loadMap(address string, title string) ([]byte, error) {
    mapHost := "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap"

    v := url.Values{}
    v.Add("center", address)
    v.Add("zoom", "15")
    v.Add("scale", "2")
    v.Add("size", "400x350")
    v.Add("markers", address)
    v.Add("sensor", "false")
    v.Add("key", apiKey)
    mapURL := mapHost + "?" + v.Encode()

    filename := title + ".png"
    for i := 0; i < 30; i++ {
        body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
        if err == nil {
            return body, nil
        }

        if i == 0 {
            fmt.Println("Getting map for " + address + " and saving it to " + filename)
            fmt.Println("Map URL: " + mapURL)
            httpClientGetMap, _ := http.Get(mapURL)
            body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(httpClientGetMap.Body)
            ioutil.WriteFile(filename, []byte(body), 0600)
        }

        i++
    }

    return nil, errors.New("Failed to get an image")
}

// viewHandler returns the map image
func viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    address := r.URL.Query().Get("address")

    md5 := md5.Sum([]byte(address))
    title := hex.EncodeToString(md5[:])
    p, err := loadMap(address, title)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusGatewayTimeout)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("content-type", "image/png")
    w.Write(p)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/getmap", viewHandler)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Improve the for loop

The `loadMap` method is really hard to read, and is not verry efficient:

Currently, if a file doesn't exists, here are the steps followed by the method:

- try to read the content of a file to see if it exists
- send a request to google map, and write the response to a file
- read the content of the new file

but we could merge just return the response instead of reading the file twice ! 
Also, it would be better to have a `map` for keeping records of saved map. 
To do this, we create a `server` that implement the `ServerHTTP` method:

```
  type server struct {
    mux        *http.ServeMux
    fetchedMap map[string]string
  }

  func (s *server) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
      s.mux.ServeHTTP(w, r)
  }
```

Now, let's rewritte the loadMap method:

```
  func (s *server) loadMap(address string, title string) ([]byte, error) {

    if filename, ok := s.fetchedMap[title]; ok {
        return ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    }
    mapHost := "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap"

    v := url.Values{}
    v.Add("center", address)
    v.Add("zoom", "15")
    v.Add("scale", "2")
    v.Add("size", "400x350")
    v.Add("markers", address)
    v.Add("sensor", "false")
    v.Add("key", apiKey)
    mapURL := mapHost + "?" + v.Encode()

    fmt.Println("Getting map for " + address + " and saving it to " + filename)
    fmt.Println("Map URL: " + mapURL)
    httpClientGetMap, _ := http.Get(mapURL)
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(httpClientGetMap.Body)
    ioutil.WriteFile(filename, []byte(body), 0600)
    return body, nil
  }
```

The steps are now:

- check if requested address has already been fetched, and if yes, return file content
- if no fetch map from google map and write it to a file
- return the map

### General advices

- use constant for `mapHost` and other constant parameters
- use `fmt.Printf("%v", str)` instead of `fmt.Println(" " + str)` because it's easier to read
- **Always** check the error ! Silently discarding errors is really dangerous
- avoid useless conversion: `body` is already a slice of byte

Here is the new version of the code:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/hex"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "os"
)

var apiKey = os.Getenv("API_KEY")

const (
    baseURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap"
    zoom    = "15"
    scale   = "2"
    size    = "400x350"
)

func (s *server) loadMap(address string, title string) ([]byte, error) {

    if filename, ok := s.fetchedMap[title]; ok {
        return ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
    }
    v := url.Values{
        "center":  {address},
        "zoom":    {zoom},
        "scale":   {scale},
        "size":    {size},
        "markers": {address},
        "sensor":  {"false"},
        "key":     {apiKey},
    }
    mapURL := baseURL + "?" + v.Encode()
    filename := title + ".png"

    fmt.Printf("Getting map for adress %s and saving it to %s\nMap URL: %s\n", address, filename, mapURL)

    httpClientGetMap, err := http.Get(mapURL)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(httpClientGetMap.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    err = ioutil.WriteFile(filename, body, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    s.fetchedMap[title] = filename
    return body, nil
}

func (s *server) viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    address := r.URL.Query().Get("address")

    checksum := md5.Sum([]byte(address))
    title := hex.EncodeToString(checksum[:])
    mapByte, err := s.loadMap(address, title)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusGatewayTimeout)
        return
    }
    w.Header().Set("content-type", "image/png")
    w.Write(mapByte)
}

type server struct {
    mux        *http.ServeMux
    fetchedMap map[string]string
}

func (s *server) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    s.mux.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}

func main() {

    s := &server{
        mux:        http.DefaultServeMux,
        fetchedMap: map[string]string{},
    }
    s.mux.HandleFunc("/getmap", s.viewHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", s)
}
```